# Xamarin UI test - how to open navigation drawer

Tags: xamarin

I am testing my android app using Xamarin UI Testing tool and I have written the following test:

```
public void login()
    {
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("Activity.LoginActivity.RelativeLayout_email"));
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("EditText_email"));
        app.EnterText(x => x.Id("EditText_email"), "matt@matt.matt");
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("EditText_password"));
        app.EnterText(x => x.Id("EditText_password"), "matt123");
        app.PressEnter();
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("Button_login"));
        app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("ImageView_OfferItem_photo"), timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
        app.SwipeLeftToRight();
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("ImageView_OfferItem_photo").Index(1));
    }
```

and at the end I want to open side navigation drawer but I am unable to do it, because I am using native menu icon, that has no id. I tried android.R.id.home, but it did not work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. According to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsU8vg1_g0s&feature=youtu.be&t=7m28s I made app.Repl in my test and then flashed my element. Element did not have id (id=null), but it did have right coordinates (84,159 in my context), however menu icon is in the top left corner.

Answer (score 2):

```
app.SwipeLeftToRight(0.99);
```

You can  also swipe to open menu, like this :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `app.TapCoordinates`. I assume the navigation drawer will always be in the top left corner, so you can just use something like `app.TapCoordinates(10,10)`

Comment: I tried that, too. With many coordinates, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just search the humberger icon using the class "AppCompatImageButton"

app.Tap(c => c.Class("AppCompatImageButton"));